# GitHub for windows crashes on launch

Tags: windows, github, github-for-windows

Recently tried to install GitHub for windows on a machine.
At first, it seemed nothing happened at all, but then I looked in the event log, and it throws the following errors:

```
Application: GitHub.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.ComponentModel.Composition.CompositionException
Stack:
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window)
   at GitHub.App.Main()
```

and

```
Faulting application name: GitHub.exe, version: 2.7.0.24, time stamp: 0x54b6e999
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.3.9600.17415, time stamp: 0x54504ade
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x00014598
Faulting process ID: 0x17c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d04121296c645b
Faulting application path: C:\Users\hh\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\8CX4XLVA.M6L\72MGD9Z3.PMC\gith..tion_317444273a93ac29_0002.0007_cc7bcd60c65d01d4\GitHub.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report ID: 68ed4e46-ad14-11e4-825a-002564a874bc
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Anyone experienced this before?

Comment: The creators of the GitHub for Windows app are probably better able to help you with this. You can contact them at [github.com/contact](https://github.com/contact)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the people of the future:

I talked to GitHub about this, and sent them detailed error reports and so on, and suddenly, a couple of months later, it worked! They never actually told me they fixed the problem, but hey, seems like it ;)